# Is it possible to run the validate process in rasa-core forms after it is set before the form activating?

Tags: python-3.x, forms, rasa-core

Currently I can get the bot to follow the specific path I want, ie conversation to make a form. I know that if you have a slot set earlier before the form is activated it will skip that slot in required slots look for that slot.

my action.py is set up to catch name, food, quantity and address and works if inform is empty or doesnt have name `* inform{food:pizza}` which action_food_form kicks in and  it will fill all the slot we need in the form and validate name to `prev_customers`

```
prev_customers = [kevin, ...]
```

an example (stories.md)

Can we validate the `name:kevin` slot and check if it is in the `prev_customers` instead of skipping that slot without validating?

Try validate all slots even it is set already before moving forward in the next required_slot?

```
* inform{name: kevin, food:pizza}  // [pizza](food) for [kevin](name)
  - action_food_form
  - form{"name":"action_food_form'}
  - form{"name":null}
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the way forward but, I have been thinking of adding an extra validation if (name) is filled before form validation and therefore form_action doesn't need to care about the set slot

Comment: Wish these questions would get an actual answer from the rasa dev's...

Answer (score 0):

here is a Rasa Dev :-) 
You could overwrite the `validate` [function here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk/blob/b18f088446e405608b74193e84c0d82ddfe6af47/rasa_sdk/forms.py#L340).

Probably something along these lines:

```
    def validate(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        # type: (CollectingDispatcher, Tracker, Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict]
        """Extract and validate value of requested slot.
        If nothing was extracted reject execution of the form action.
        Subclass this method to add custom validation and rejection logic
        """

        # extract other slots that were not requested
        # but set by corresponding entity or trigger intent mapping
        slot_values = self.extract_other_slots(dispatcher, tracker, domain)

        slot_value = slot_values.get("slot_name")
        events = []
        if not_is_valid(slot_value):
           events.append(SlotSet("slot_name", "slot_value"))

        # TODO validate others

        return events
```